# Why are my grid-template-row settings affecting columns?

Tags: css, css-grid

I am trying to set the rows to be `grid-template-rows: 30px 1fr;` so that the first row is `30px` and all subsequent rows take up the height they need but it looks like this styling is affecting the 3rd item in the column.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.cont {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 30px 1fr;
  grid-gap: 2px;
}
.cont div {
  background: red;
  height: 90px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You define 3 columns but 5 divs are not fill these columns "correctly". If you add a 6th div you can see the correct result what you want.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.cont {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 30px 1fr;
  grid-gap: 2px;
}
.cont div {
  background: red;
  /*height: 90px;*/
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks..why does it look like 1 row?  Shouldn't `grip-gap` be adding a row gap to it?

Comment: Hmm... I found the problem ant this is really interesting. The `height: 90px;` is override grid-gap

Answer (score 0):

You are having an overflow. You are putting an element with a height equal to `90px` inside a row equal to `30px`

Add some opacity to better understand:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.cont {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 30px 1fr;
  grid-gap: 2px;
}

.cont div {
  background: red;
  border:5px solid ;
  height: 90px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

You can clearly see how the elements of the first row are ovelapping the one of the second row:

Comment: thanks, so I can leave the `height` off the element then since the grid definition is defining that, right?

Comment: @RicardoAlvveroa ues, no need to set any explicit height if you do it in the template